# How to translate Twig date

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig, translate

I am using Twig for my project as an Template engine.

The thing i want to achieve is Translate name of the months. For instance `30 December` to `30 Декабрь`

Project wasn't built upon symfony or any other framework. It is just project built upon PHP7 with MVC pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the **Twig Extensions** library, which provides several useful extensions for Twig: https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

It is developed by the same people who built the Twig template engine.

You can use the **i18n Extension** (https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html), then, in your code, you'll use the `trans` block to mark parts in the template as translatable:

```
{% trans "Hello World!" %}

{% trans string_var %}

{% trans %}
    Hello World!
{% endtrans %}

{% set name = object.name_property %}

{% trans %}
    Hello {{ name }}!
{% endtrans %}
```

---

If you just want a quick solution for translation of month names and you don't want to overload your project with other dependecies, you can create a simple **Twig filter**, as described here: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters.

```
$filter = new Twig_Filter('trans', function ($string) {
    // $string is the month name...
    // return the translated string
    return ... ;
});

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

Then use it in your template:

```
{{ 'December'|trans }}
```